# What is the font size, font color, shadow color & offset in UITableView section header?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am reproducing the original UITableView section header using custom graphics.

What is the font size, font color, shadow color & offset in UITableView section header ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UILabel * headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
headerLabel.opaque = NO;
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0);
```

Hope this will fulfill your requirements...

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.265 green:0.294 blue:0.367 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the pre-iOS7 look, I got good results with:

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] init];
headerView.textLabel.text = title;
headerView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
headerView.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.40 green:0.42 blue:0.43 alpha:1.0];
headerView.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
```

If you're not using `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, then create one as a test and grab its label's other attributes (font, etc.).